# HTML5 Anyway to include a submit button directly into a input type="text"

Tags: html

HTML5 Anyway to include a submit button directly into a input type="text"?

For instance when the user types in something, a button "submit" appears inside the textarea?

Another way to look at it, can u define 2 types in one input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't define two input types in the same input element.

To achieve what you want you'd need to define a separate input element for your button, and use CSS and JavaScript to position it and make it appear/disappear etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7C87x/) (using jQuery for convenience.) The code could be cleaned up, but that's the general idea.